# flatpickr calendar errors in console

Tags: javascript

Good evening, help with solving the problem.
There is one big js in which everything is collected up to the heap. After connecting the flatpickr calendar in the console, it erases a number of errors (the bulk of them also falls on prototype.js v1.7, without connecting the calendar all ok).

TypeError:

```
Cannot read property '-1' of undefined dt-base.js:8240
at dt-base.js:7949
at dt-base.js:869
at dt-base.js:829
at Array.forEach ()
at Array.each (dt-base.js:828)
at Array.collect (dt-base.js:868)
at Object.formatDate (dt-base.js:7948)
at createDay (dt-base.js:6897)
at buildDays (dt-base.js:6993)
at build (dt-base.js:6858)
```

Explanation of strings:

```
dt-base.js:8240 - console.error(e)
dt-base.js:7949 - return formats[c] && arr[i - 1] !== "\\"
dt-base.js:869 - results.push(iterator.call(context, value, index))
dt-base.js:829 - iterator.call(context, value, index++)
dt-base.js:828 - this._each(function(value) {
dt-base.js:868 - this.each(function(value, index) {
dt-base.js:7948 - .map(function (c, i, arr) {
dt-base.js:6897 - dayElement.setAttribute("aria-label", self.formatDate(date, self.config.ariaDateFormat));
dt-base.js:6993 - days.appendChild(createDay("prevMonthDay", new Date(self.currentYear, self.currentMonth - 1, dayNumber), dayNumber, dayIndex));
dt-base.js:6858 - buildDays();
```